# Send notification for an email only if its an email of an user registered in the conference

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page where a user can send notifications for users that are registered in a conference. In this page the user can select that wants to send a notification for all participants registered in a conference. But the user can also select that he wants to send an email for a specific user registred in a conference. I have the code below to achieve this.

The notification for all participants registered in a specific conference is working fine.

The issue is in sending a notification for a specific email that the user introduce in the "participant_email" form field. The issue is that the email is sent to any email but the notification should only be sent to a user that has a registration in the conference, otherwise should appear an error.

Do you know how to achieve that? In the code below is working for the all participants case, that is, if the user send a notification for all participatns and there are no participants registered, the notification is not sent and it appears "There are no participants registered in the conference.". But how to achieve also that if the user is sending a notification for a specific email that is not an email of a user registered in the conference?

```
public function send(Request $request, $id){

    $conference = Conference::find($id);

    $message = $request->message;
    $subject = $request->subject;
     // if the user selected that wants to send email for a specific participant of the conference
    if($request->send_to == "participant"){
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'participant_email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',                                             
        ]);

        Mail::to($request->participant_email)->send(new Notification($conference, $message, $subject));

        Session::flash('success', 'Notification sent.');

        return redirect()->back();
    }
    // if the user selected that wants to send an email for all participants of the conference
    if($request->send_to == "all"){

        $sendTo = User::whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use($id) {
            $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
        })->get();
    }else{
       $sendTo = User::whereHas('registrations.participants.registration_type', function ($query) use ($id, $request) {
              $query->where('id', '=', $request->send_to)
                 ->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
              })->whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use ($id) {
                  $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
              })->get(); 
    }

    foreach($sendTo as $user){
        $usersEmail[] = $user->email;
    }

    if(isset($usersEmail)) {
        foreach ($usersEmail as $userEmail) {
            Mail::to($userEmail)->send(new Notification($conference, $message, $subject));
        }
        Session::flash('success', 'Notification sent with success.');
        return redirect()->back();

    }
    else{
        Session::flash('no_participants', 'There are no participants registered in the conference.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Updated code:

```
class NotificationController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id){

        $conference = Conference::find($id);
        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conference_id', $id)->get();


        return view('notifications.index')->with('conference', $conference)->with('registrationType', $registrationType);
    }

    public function send(Request $request, $id){


        $conference = Conference::find($id);


        $this->validate(request(), [
            'send_to' => 'required',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required' // The message field is required.
        ]);


        $message = $request->message;
        $subject = $request->subject;

        if($request->send_to == "participant"){
            $this->validate(request(), $this->participantRules($id));
            $emails[] = $request->participant_email;
        }

        else if($request->send_to == "all"){
            $emails = User::whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use($id) {
                $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->pluck('email');
        }


        else{
            $emails = User::whereHas('registrations.participants.registration_type', function ($query) use ($id, $request) {
                $query->where('id', '=', $request->send_to)
                    ->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use ($id) {
                $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->get(); // use pluck('email') instead of get to select only email

        }

        if(count($emails) > 0) {
            $this->sendNotification($emails, $conference, $request);
            Session::flash('success', 'Notificação enviada com sucesso.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            Session::flash('no_participants', 'There are no participants registered in the conference.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }

    protected function participantRules($conferenceID){
        return [
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'email',
                Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) use ($conferenceID) {
                    $query->whereHas('registrations',  function ($query) use($conferenceID) {
                        $query->where('conference_id', '=', $conferenceID);
                    });
                }),
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function sendNotification(array $emails, $conference, $request){
        foreach ($emails as $userEmail) {
            Mail::to($userEmail)->send(new Notification($conference, $request->message, $request->subject));
        }

        Session::flash('success', 'Notificaiton sent with success.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Comment: you want to add validation on `participant_email` that the email should be registered in conference right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add extra filter to `exists` validation like this

```
public function send(Request $request, $id){

    $conference = Conference::find($id);

    $message = $request->message;
    $subject = $request->subject;
    $emails = []; 

    if($request->send_to == "participant"){
        $this->validate(request(), $this->participantRules($id));

        $emails = User::whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use($id) {
                       $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
                    })->where('email', $request->participant_email)->pluck('email');

    }else if($request->send_to == "all"){
        $emails = User::whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use($id) {
            $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
        })->pluck('email');
    }else{
        $emails = User::whereHas('registrations.participants.registration_type', function ($query) use ($id, $request) {
            $query->where('id', '=', $request->send_to)
                  ->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use ($id) {
               $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
            })->pluck('email'); 

    }

    if(count($emails) > 0) {
        $this->sendNotification($emails, $conference, $request);
        Session::flash('success', 'Notification sent with success.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }else{
        Session::flash('no_participants', 'There are no participants registered in the conference.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Validation Rules

```
protected function participantRules($conferenceId){
    return [
        'participant_email' => 'required|email'
    ];
}
```

Send notification

```
protected function sendNotification($emails, $conference, $request){
    foreach ($emails as $userEmail) {
        Mail::to($userEmail)->send(new Notification($conference, $request->message, $request->subject));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also updated the question with this part, because the user can also send email to all participants associated with a specific registration type selected by the user: "else{
       $sendTo =  User::whereHas('registrations.participants.registration_type', function ($query) use ($id, $request) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $request->send_to)
        ->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
})->whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('conference_id', '=', $id);
})->get();  }". Is only necessary to add that after " else if($request->send_to == "all")"?

Comment: yes, you can add after that, but you have to return `$emails` array in that else condition.

Comment: what does else condition do ? use `pluck` instead get so that you will get array of emails

Comment: I updated the question with the complete NotificationController, the validation when the user selects that wants to send an email for a specific conference is not working properly. For example the user selects that he wants to send an email for a specific email, in the email field introduce the email and in the subject and message fields introduce some text and click "Send". The message that appears is "The email field is required." But it should appear "There are no participants registered in the conference." because the introduced email is not an email of a user registered in the conference.

Comment: The email field is required is incorrect because the email field was filled by the user.

Comment: my mistake, it should be participant_email in validation and then you can add custom message for validation

Comment: Thanks, like that appears "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'participant_email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `participant_email` = ...@....com and (`has` = registrations))".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177047/discussion-between-rkj-and-john).